# Code behind code is not reflecting in VS 2017 Web Application Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on a project created as "Web Application Project" in C#, I am trying to implement new functionality to existing pages. Changes done on aspx page are working properly but when I add code into code behind file, changes are not reflecting. Things I have tried:

- Deleted Temporary system and Visual studio files.
- Deleted Code behind file of the page (Project is still successfully
  build and working on browser)

Below is the message I am getting when I try to put break point:
[image]

Comment: Did you rebuild? Do you have compilation errors?

Comment: Just as test, can you add a new page and test whether the code behind there works? If so, do you notice any differences with your problem page?

Comment: There was some kind of DLL reference issue in my project(Project is using DLLs from some unknown location). Last thing I did is delete the project and fetched from TFS. Now it is working fine.

Comment: @MaxPayne. It seems that you have missed some symbol files of the extra dlls. And glad to know that you have fixed the issue. To help other community members handle and search similar issues, I have added your tips into the answer and you can check it. Maybe marking it could help improve this ticket.

Comment: @MaxPayne Anyway, have a nice day! And if you have any other problems, please feel free to let us know::)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following suggestions:

**1)** disable the option `Require source files to exactly match the original version` under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**General**

and also disable Enable Just My Code under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**General**

**2)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. And then restart your project to test again.

**3)** right-click on the project **Properties**-->**Build**-->**Advanced**--> and make sure that you have set **Debugging information** to `Full`.

**4)** delete all files under `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v*.*.****\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`

and
`C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

================================================

**Update from MaxPayne:**

There was some kind of DLL reference issue in my project(Project is using DLLs from some unknown location). And it seems that the symbol files of them are missing.

**Delete the project and fetched from TFS. Now it is working fine.**

Answer (score 0):

What are you seeing here is very simple... the process that you have attached is not matching this code, this could be to many reasons:

- You have the code deployed to another location and you have not updated one or more dll's.
- Your pdb file could be outdated.
- You are attaching the wrong process (very common in web applications, as you can see more than one w3wp process.
- You have the build location changed to another wrong place.
- Also try to clear the temp file for ASP.NET.

Bottom line make sure that all dll's are rebuilt and updated successfully and should work fine.